# Getting values on particular index in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button and onclick of that button, i am running a AJAX call and getting values from another jsp page. My rows are indexed.

```js
<%

List<DiskSheet> ds1 = new ArrayList<DiskSheet>();
if (request.getParameter("numLLP") != null && !request.getParameter("numLLP").isEmpty()) {
 int numLLP = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("numLLP"));
 for (int i=0;i<numLLP;i++) {
  DiskSheet d = new DiskSheet();
 
  d.setCH5Limiter(request.getParameter("limiter_"+i));
  d.setMfrPrice(request.getParameter("diskvalues_"+i));
  d.setDiskCyc(request.getParameter("diskcyc"));  
  
  ds1.add(d);
 }
 request.getSession().setAttribute("engine" + request.getParameter("diskid"), ds1);
 
}


<% 
List<DiskSheet> ds =  (List<DiskSheet>) request.getSession().getAttribute("engine" + request.getParameter("diskid"));
if (ds == null) {
 ds = new ArrayList<DiskSheet>();
}
String disksheet = request.getParameter("disksheet");
if (disksheet != "") {
 String engine = request.getParameter("Engines");
 if (ds.size() == 0) {
  ds = DiskSheet.getLLPEngine(engine);
 }
 
%>
```

```html
     <div><input type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="limiter_<%=i%>" id="limiter" class="limiter" value="<%=airs.getCH5Limiter()%>" size="10" onblur="getDiskSheetCyc()"></div>  

     <div><input type="hidden" class="diskvalues" id="diskvalues" name="diskvalues_<%=i%>" size="10"  value="<%=airs.getMfrPrice()%>" onblur="getDiskSheetCyc()"></div>
     
   <div><input type="text" class="diskcyc" id="diskcyc" name="diskcyc" size="10"  value="<%=airs.getDiskCyc()%>" onblur="getDiskSheetCyc()"></div>
```

I am trying to perform a simple calculation and print the values in the third row however, it only displays the value in one of the cells. Here's what i tried.

```js
function showPopup(diskid){
 document.getElementById("popup_win").style.display = 'block';
 }
  
  
  function getDiskSheet(diskid) {
  var form = document.getElementById("airplaneForm"); 
  var id = diskid;
 
  var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater("ch5limiteroutput",
    "/jsp/Ch5Limiter.jsp", {
     asynchronous : true,
     postBody : Form.serialize(form), 
     data: id,
     method : 'post',

     onComplete : function() {
      displayLimiter();
      getDiskSheetCyc();
      document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = id;
    }

    });
  
 }

 function displayLimiter() {
  var form = document.getElementById("airplaneForm");
   
  var limiteroutput = document.getElementById("ch5limiteroutput").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("limiter").innerHTML = limiteroutput;
 }
  
   function getDiskSheetCyc(){
  var diskvalues = document.getElementsByClassName("diskvalues");
  var limiter = document.getElementsByClassName("limiter");
  
   for (var i = 0; i < diskvalues.length; i++) {
    
    var diskval = parseInt(diskvalues[i].value);
    var limiter = parseInt(limiter[i].value);    
    diskcyc = diskval/limiter;
    
      }
   document.getElementById('diskcyc').value = diskcyc;   

 }
```

```html
<td class="trigger_popup" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1"><input type="button" id="1" value="Disk Sheet" name="disksheet" class="disksheet" onclick="showPopup(this.id);getDiskSheet(this.id);"> </a>
</td>

<div class="popup_win" id="popup_win">
 <span class="helper"></span>
 <div>
<br>
<div id="TableBox" class="TableBox" style="width: 110%;">
 
   <div>
    <div><span class="id" id="id"></span></div>
     <div><span class="limiter" id="limiter"></span></div>  
  </div> 
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>

<div id="ch5limiteroutput" style="display: none"></div>
```

Also tried doing it through jQuery but it doesn't seem to go inside the loop. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
function getDiskSheetCyc(){
          const jQuerytable = jQuery('#TableBox');
          const jQueryrow = jQuerytable.find('> div');

          jQuery(".jQueryrow").each(function() {
            const jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
            const diskvalues = parseInt(jQuerythis.find('.diskvalues').val());
            const limiter  = parseInt(jQuerythis.find('.limiter').val());
            const diskcyc = diskvalues/limiter;
            if (!isNaN(diskcyc)) jQuerythis.find('.diskcyc').val(diskcyc);                   
          });   

    }
```

Comment: can you setup a code snippet to see the whole setup?

Comment: @estavillo i edited the post a little. It doesn't let me actually run the snippet properly because of the ajax call but i have included how my page is setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code at present does not make a lot of sense. For a jQuery solution, consider the following code example.

```js
$(function() {
  function showPopup() {
    $("#popup_win").show();
  }

  function displayLimiter() {
    var limiteroutput = $("#ch5limiteroutput").html();
    $("#limiter").html(limiteroutput);
  }

  function getDiskSheetCyc() {
    var diskvalues = $(".diskvalues");
    var limiter = $(".limiter");
    var diskcyc = 0;

    diskvalues.each(function(i, el) {
      var diskval = $(el).val() == "" ? parseInt($(el).val()) : 0;
      var limiter = $(el).val() == "" ? parseInt($(el).val()) : 0;
      if (diskval > limiter) {
        diskcyc = diskval / limiter;
      }
    });
    $('#diskcyc').val(diskcyc);
  }

  function getDiskSheet(diskid) {
    var form = $("#airplaneForm");
    var id = diskid;

    $.post("/jsp/Ch5Limiter.jsp", {
      postBody: form.serialize(),
      data: id
    }, function(results) {
      displayLimiter();
      getDiskSheetCyc();
      $("#id").val(id);
    });
  }

  $("[type='button']").click(function() {
    showPopup();
    getDiskSheet($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="trigger_popup">
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1"><input type="button" id="1" value="Disk Sheet" name="disksheet" class="disksheet"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="popup window" id="popup_win" style="display: none;">
  <span class="helper"></span>
  <div>
    <br>
    <div id="TableBox" class="TableBox" style="width: 110%;">
      <div>
        <div><span class="id" id="id"></span></div>
        <div><span class="limiter" id="limiter"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="ch5limiteroutput" style="display: none"></div>
```

So this encounters issues all over due to a number of missing elements that were not provided. The basic idea is you want to show a popup, post some data, and then update some content. I don't see where you do anything with data returned from the AJAX call... I am guessing it's just updating the DB with no feedback.

It would be helpful to provide an example of the data that is retuened if you need more help there.

In regards to the calculation, you're on the right path. You just need to make sure the proper fields get populated with the right details. I am assuming this is where the data from the POST gets to be used.

Examine your Network tab in development tools. You should see the POST action, the Headers, and the Response. This should help you identify if you're getting an error in your AJAX or maybe getting different data back than expected.